# How can i get a sting from a cell within captions?

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Is it possible to get the text between two captions in a cell?

Example:

Cell A1 contains "Dwayne 'TheRock' Johnson" and I'm trying to get a formula where Cell A2 gets "TheRock" from cell A1.

So I can get just the nickname of the people listed that are always within ''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\'.*\'")
```

result

A1=Dwayne 'TheRock' Johnson

A2='TheRock'

Comment: Thank you sir, just if you would indulge me because i'm too stupid to figure out how to do it within the formula, what if i don't want the '' ?

Comment: @user3227675 there are many methods to resolve that this one of theme =REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\'(.*?)\'")

Comment: i appriciate it, if you want to have a laugh, my excel skills are so bad that my best idea was to create another cell next to it and use =SUBSTITUTE(A2, "'","") :'(